# Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=ezfb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, config

I included new module ezfb getting error "Failed to instantiate module".

I followed this plugin - http://plnkr.co/edit/UMUtFc?p=preview

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ezfb', 'ui.router', 'ngStorage', 'ngCookies', 'ngDialog', 'ngAnimate', 'treasure-overlay-spinner', 'satellizer']);
    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', '$authProvider', '$provide','ezfb',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, $authProvider, $provide, ezfbProvider) {

    ezfbProvider.setInitParams({
            appId : '386469651480295'
        });

    }]);
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Myapps</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
<body class="nav-md" ng-app="myApp">

        <div ui-view></div>
        <script src="vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/files/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/ngstorage/ngStorage.js"></script>
        <!-- end angular theme -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins/angular-easyfb.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/login_controller.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the file js/plugins/angular-easyfb.js present in this location?

Answer (score 0):

It should be the problem in file ordering. please swap these files as below

```
<script src="js/plugins/angular-easyfb.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried now but getting same error. Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=ezfb